# Printing a checked checkbox / tick box with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have the following problem: I have to use an HTML->PDF conversion service to render a piece of HTML. However, this service is a bit limited in it's functionality, so I need a way to "work around" it.

I'm mainly just printing text, so it's not a big deal, but the only problem is that I have to print some "unticked" and some "ticked" check boxes, my converter is failing at this. In particular I've tried:

- Using the unicode `&#x2610;` ("☐") and `&#x2611;` ("☑") characters, but the converter doesn't render them (probably the font it's using doesn't
  have them)
- Using the WingDing characters `&#254;` and `&#168;` but again, the wingding font is not recognized
- The converter doesn't support images, so can't just use an image

I was thinking, at this point, to "simulate" a checkbox by using spans with borders, something like:

```
<span style="border: 1px solid black; height: 12px; width: 12px;"></span>
```

However, I can't make it look correct (no fault of the converter this time, even browsers show the above as just one vertival line.

Can anyone help me "draw" checkboxes using just "basic" html elements? What would be the cleanest way?

PS: checkboxes need to be inline with the text.

Comment: HTML is not a graphics generating tool so there is no way to help you with this.

Comment: Out of curiosity does CSS generated content get printed in the output? If not then the only realistic answer, given that images don't get converted/printed, would be to upgrade the tool you're using (though for that question, [softwarerecs.se] would be the place to ask, given that tool recommendations are off-topic here on [SO]). Further, it might be worth your while linking to the tool/service you're using (assuming it's free to use then it allows us to run through the various options we can think of without having to continually ask you questions about it, and its output possibilities).

Comment: @DavidThomas: It renders CSS. The tool is not publicly available unfortunately (it's a service provided by our client's servers and they want to use that, despite its limitations, for whatever reasons)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Using HTML and CSS:

```css
/* The standalone checkbox square*/
.checkbox {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* This is what simulates a checkmark icon */
.checkbox.checked:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 7px;
  
  /* "Center" the checkmark */
  position:relative;
  top:4px;
  left:7px;
  
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox"></div> Unchecked<br><br>

<div class="checkbox checked"></div> Checked
```

The reason YOUR code didn't work was because you were using a `span` element, which is an inline element. You *can* use a `span` for this, but you'll need to add the style of `display: block` to the element (making it act as a block element instead of an inline element).

The `div` tag is a block, so no need for setting it's `display` style. If you would like the `div` to display inline, set the `display: inline-block`

Comment: Thanks, but this is the easy part. What about a **checked** checkbox? Even just that same square but crossed would suffice for my needs.

Comment: You neglect to mention the reason the element can't be an `display: inline` element; which is simply because a `width` property isn't applied to those elements, because their size is based upon their contained content.

Comment: That's just awesome :D Great work, looks perfect
EDIT: although it seems it forces a line-break... so it kinda defeats the purpose for me, as I have to display it in-line :(

Comment: Ok, adding display: inline; option to the unchecked one works properly. Re-accepted as answer.

Comment: I've reflected my code to fit your inline goal. Glad it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; 
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px; 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 4px;">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8rt4dqfc/

Comment: Thanks, but this is the easy part. What about a **checked** checkbox? Even just that same square but crossed would suffice for my needs.